# Function exists in PySide but still getting attribute error

Tags: python, pyside, attributeerror

I'm going through the examples that come with pyside. While running the http example under site-packages/PySide/examples/network/http/ I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'PySide.QtNetwork.QHttp' object has no attribute 'sslErrors'
```

This attribute most definitely exists - or, at least, it's supposed to according to this:

http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtNetwork/QHttp.html#PySide.QtNetwork.PySide.QtNetwork.QHttp.sslErrors

While debugging I did a dir() on the loaded object and I did not see sslErrors().

Any idea on what could be occurring?
Note that I have not modified the code at all. I'm just running the example as is.

Comment: What is the source of your PySide library? I have got a similar issue using the Anaconda package, while it seems to work with the current PyPi (1.2.4) installation.

Comment: I also installed PySide via Anaconda (1.2.1), and have similar issues with the QSslConfiguration not existing. Seems like Anaconda is just broken.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that your PySide and/or Qt libraries were built without SSL support. You might be able to quickly verify this by checking the output of:

```
    QtNetwork.QSslSocket.supportsSsl()
```

For more details on this, see [Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) Classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/ssl.html) in the Qt docs.

PS:

The `QHttp.sslErrors` signal is certainly present in the PySide-1.2.1 installation on my Linux system (which does have the necessary SSL support).

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the http.py example, running Python 2.7.6, 32 bits and PySide 1.2.1 and this program works without any problem. May I suggest re-installing/updating PySide?

To check which version of PySide you have:

```
>>> import PySide
>>> PySide.__version__
'1.2.1'
```